# mongoexport error: Failed: Failed to parse + Unrecognized field 'snapshot

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, data-migration, mongoexport

Goal:to migrate my local mongodb data to mongobd atlas cluster.

Try:
1. export local data as json.
2. import json to cluster.

OS: Linuxmint 19.1 Cinnamon
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
mongod --version
db version v3.6.3
I also have a separate database folder.

So first I started

```
/home/me/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath=/home/me/mongodb-data
```

then I opened a terminal and typed

```
~/mongodb/bin $ mongoexport  --db task-manager --collection users --out ~/Desktop/test.json
```

I expected the users collection from task-manager database will print out as a test.json file but I am getting the error:

```
2019-06-18T22:05:06.108+0200    connected to: localhost
2019-06-18T22:05:06.108+0200    Failed: Failed to parse: { find: "users", filter: {}, sort: {}, skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "task-manager" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

What's wrong and what should I do to fix it? Is there any better way to migrate data?

Comment: Your mongo-tools (that contains mongoexport) version is incompatible with your mongo server version, you should use the latest version. To migrate data, consider using mongodump/mongorestore, which is generally faster than a json export.

Comment: yeah I do realize that. Although I have no idea why my db is showing up lower version... I remember when I installed it it was 4 or sth... I am trying to update but have encountered some repo issues. Will try again later.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

so I uninstalled everything mongodb and downloaded the server, shell and tool deb from their website and made sure they're all 4.0.10 for Ubuntu 18.04. Although the same version seems to be included in the synaptic, I decided to go directly install the deb, just in case, as I previously did command line installation and also from Software Manager which ended up having different versions. With versions correctly, I finally can output the json file as I wanted. I would also try the mongodump and mongorestore methods as @sachav mentioned.

Comment: How would you solve this for a production environment?

Answer (score 47):

This usually happens due to different versions of mongodump vs your mongoDB server.

But adding `--forceTableScan` switch can solve the problem

```
mongodump --forceTableScan -d database_name
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the mongo snapshot functionality which was introduced in mongo 4.0
You will face this if mongo client is below 4.0 and db is on above 4.0
You can fix this by two option:

1. using --forceTableScan
2. download the latest mongo [client](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/) as per your OS and fire the command, you should not see the error
   Note: same things happens to **mongodump**